# call oracle procedure using asp.net and edit gridview row from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, session-variables, edit

I am stuck because when i update the edit page on button click event, my page navigates to the home page that contains the `gridview` but the `gridview` row is not updated and remains the same. And please advice me how i can edit a page on a button click event using session.

This is the manager aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"  GridLines="Vertical" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
   <%--   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"  GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="USERID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">--%>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERID" HeaderText="USERID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="USERID"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRSTNAME" HeaderText="FIRSTNAME" SortExpression="FIRSTNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LASTNAME" HeaderText="LASTNAME" SortExpression="LASTNAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="EMAIL" SortExpression="EMAIL" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PASSWORD" HeaderText="PASSWORD" SortExpression="PASSWORD" />
            <asp:TemplateField >  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  CommandName="EditButton" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>--%>
                          <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Width="60" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditButton" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />  
                    </ItemTemplate>  

                </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField>   
                <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"  CommandName="DeleteButton" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

                     </ItemTemplate>  
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        <%--    hiddenfield for session--%>
              <%--<asp:TemplateField>   
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdid" Value='<%#Eval("USERID")%>' runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Navigate to `edit.aspx` page on clicking of edit button:

```
namespace WebApplicationSystem
{
    public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int empno = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            empno = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["USERID"].ToString());

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindTextBoxvalues();
            }
        }

        private void BindTextBoxvalues()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from LOGIN where USERID=" + empno, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter Oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            Oda.Fill(dt);

            txtid.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            txtfname.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            txtlname.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            txtemail.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            txtpassword.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
        }

        protected void btnregistration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("UPDATELOGIN", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();

            OracleParameter OP1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("USERID", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            OP1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            OP1.Value = txtid;

            OracleParameter OP2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("FIRSTNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            OP2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            OP2.Value = txtfname;

            OracleParameter OP3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("LASTNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            OP3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            OP3.Value = txtlname;

            OracleParameter OP4 = cmd.Parameters.Add("EMAIL", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            OP4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            OP4.Value = txtemail;

            OracleParameter OP5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("PASSWORD", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            OP5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            OP5.Value = txtpassword;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

            //Fill the DataTable
            oda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("~/Manager.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update your `GridView` after each click, don't forget to redefine your data source:

```
GridView1.DataSource = //your DataTable
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I'm not sure that I understand what you want to do with the session manager, but you can access the session object by `HttpSessionState.Session`.

Comment: my issue is not resolved.i wann to use session variable instead of query to navigate to another page... e.g empno = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["USERID"].ToString()); instead of it i want to use session but dont know how ..

Comment: I can't figure out what you don't understand about session. Are you using the object HttpSessionState.Session ?

Comment: i want to use hidden field in datagridview throught which i wanna to generate session instead of using query string e.g GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            gridMain.SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex;
            var customerId = gridMain.Rows[gridMain.SelectedIndex].FindControl("hiddenEmployeeId") as HtmlInputHidden;
 
            if (customerId != null)
            {
                Session["custid"] = customerId.Value;
            }